Alternatives for acidic ingredients (like vinegar)
My son recently found that he needs to cut a lot of things out of his diet. Naturally, being 19 years old, he's very upset that he can't have a lot of his favorite foods.  So I've been looking for alternatives.
I found a recipe that looks like a good alternative for tomato sauce.(https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/201097/no-tomato-pasta-sauce/) but one of the ingredients is red wine vinegar.  Unfortunately, vinegar is on the list of foods he can't have.
I've read that citrus is a good replacement.  However, he has to avoid citrus as well.
I also read that amchur powder is good, but I can't find it locally.  If I can't find another substitution, I might have to get it from an online source and hope it works.
I'm ok at cooking, but not good enough to know what would make good replacements.  I need to avoid any bladder irritants, which is a lot of foods.  I can replace everything in his diet but the tomato sauce (and ketchup).  I mostly use it in pasta dishes and for pizza.
Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Pizza doesn't need tomato sauce.   There's 'pizza bianco' (white pizza) which is olive oil and garlic.  I've used pesto, and have seen people use a bechamel (white sauce, like a milk gravy).  For the ketchup, there are recipes for mushroom ketchup and stuff like indonesian 'ketjap manis' (sweet soy sauce that sometimes also has other spices)

And in general, a good resource for food substitutions in general is the website https://foodsubs.com/ ... but they cater more towards 'I can't find this', not dietary restrictions.  (so almost all of their vinegar replacements are for other types of vinegar with some modification)

There aren't a whole lot of spices that are sour.  You've already mentioned amchur powder (which you might be able to get online).
Others include:

Tamarind:  you may want to try to find it as powder to see if you like it, as it can be a bit of a mess to work with the pulp (you have to soak it, squeeze it out, then strain it)
Sumac: a tiny berry that's available dried (whole or ground up)

But I would also look at why he has to give up those foods.  Mango has citric acid in it, which may be what you're trying to avoid.  I suspect the others may be acidic as well, as that's usually why we perceive things as being sour.

He has overractive bladder and no treatments have worked yet, so his doctor suggested an elimination diet.  Looking at what he mostly eats, there's a lot of acidic ingredients (citrus, tomato, vinegar, etc).  He also has to avoid milk (found substitutions for milk and creams) and sugar.  Poor kid can't even have apples.  If this helps clear his symptoms, we're going to slowly introduce stuff back in.  I'm pretty sure that acidic foods are a strong contender for his issues.  If we wind up having to cut them out permanently, I want options.

@Jayelle what Joe is saying is that all alternatives to acidic foods are also acidic. So in that sense, you don't have options - you either discover that the problem isn't the acid after all, or your child has to eat foods which taste nothing like the foods you're replacing. Sorry to be so blunt, it sounds really unpleasant for your kid, and it's certainly not easy being the mom in that situation.

Amchur powder is sold on Amazon.com. It's also called mango powder or dried mango powder (also available on Amazon) so ask local stores if they carry that. Citric acid is another alternative that will give you the same tartness/sourness. The thing is it's not always in the food section of stores like Walmart. It can be found in the canning aisles though. Other than that, it looks like the internet is your go-to. I hope this helps you.

Try using a small amount of baking soda to neutralize the acidity of the tomatoes and add a carrot as well, the carrot will act as a natural sweetner.
Hope this helps, I understand what you are going thru, having GERD, I had to alter another of acidic recipies.
